# Prevent Chrome from jumping to the top of the page after manipulating the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, actioncable

I'm using Action Cable to build a discussion room in which users can ask questions to each other. Once a question is posted, all other users in the room will see it. I'm experiencing a strange problem on Chrome: when a question is posted by myself or another user, the page jumps to the top. This doesn't happen on other browsers and is quite an annoying problem. All my code does is append a small element to the DOM. Here's my controller:

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @question = Question.new(create_params)

    if @question.save
      ActionCable.server.broadcast(
        "discussion_room",
        message: {
          event_type: "new_question",
          question_id: @question.id,
          question_item: ApplicationController.render(partial: "questions/question_item", locals: { question: @question })
        }
      )
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end

  ...
end
```

Here's the JavaScript that handles the `new_question` event:

```
App["discussion_room"] = App.cable.subscriptions.create({ channel: "DiscussionRoomChannel", roomId: roomId },
{
  received: function(data)
  {
    switch (data.message.event_type)
    {
      case 'new_question':
        this.newQuestionEvent(data);

        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  },

  newQuestionEvent: function(data)
  {
    $("#questions-list").append(data.message.question_item);
    $("#questions-container").removeAttr("hidden");
  }
});
```

While debugging, I commented out the line that appends the HTML, and sure enough, the page no longer jumps. This is not the normal behavior of jQuery's `append` method, so I'm not sure what's going on.

What can I do to fix this issue?

Comment: What does the `data.message.question_item` value look like? Can you give an example?

Comment: @csum Thanks for your comment. Sure, I've put an example of that value here: https://pastebin.com/Gadgv1Xt

Answer (score 0):

In case you can't solve this problem here's a little trick you can use in simple javascript, to defeat this behavior...

Step 1: Save the screen row before posting a new message:

```
 var Y=window.scrollY;
```

Step 2: Post the new message by calling your usual function.

Step 3: Scroll back to the previously saved location:

```
 window.scrollTo(0,Y);
```

Answer (score 0):

After puzzling over this problem for a long time, I found out the issue is with the [`font_awesome5_rails`](https://github.com/tomkra/font_awesome5_rails) gem that I'm using. I've installed Font Awesome as an SVG using JavaScript, and whenever I take out the icons, Chrome no longer jumps to the top.

I'm going to submit an issue and also look into the problem.